# How to assure a "oneshot" service gets retried if it fails the first time?

Tags: systemd

I've read the systemd service manpage a few times, but I still cannot figure out a basic systemd pattern:

I want to run a startup process once (like a docker container, or format a drive) at bootup, successfully to completion. But if I use Type=oneshot for that, then I can't use Restart=on-failure, and if it fails, then it won't retry the job. Am I missing something obvious here?

I also tried setting Type=simple with Restart=on-failure, but this in many cases I need the following behavior (from the manpage) that oneshot services give:

> Behavior of oneshot is similar to simple; however, it is expected that the process has to exit before systemd starts follow-up units.

**Updates:**

- [Relevant upstream systemd bug](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2582).
- [And we'd also want `RemainAfterExit` semantics](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/3396)

Comment: One workaround I've used is to omit `Restart` and wrap `my_cmd`  like this: `ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'while ! my_cmd; do sleep 1; done'`, together with some reasonable `TimeoutStartSec` value.

Comment: Have you looked at [FailureAction=](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#FailureAction=)? Might be able to achieve the same thing as `Restart=` by setting `FailureAction=[self.unit]` (replace [self.unit] with the unit's name). It's kind of hacky, but at least explicit and easy enough to follow.

Comment: @Centimane `FailureAction` takes the same values as `StartLimitAction`, and all except `none` trigger a shutdown of some sort.

Answer (score 5):

One possible workaround I'm trying is

```
  [Unit]
    Description=Tags instance and EBS vols
    After=docker.service
    Requires=docker.service

    [Service]
    ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker run --rm -v /opt/tag.sh:/tag.sh -v /opt:/ack --entrypoint=/bin/sh alpine /tag.sh
    ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/sh -c '[[ -e /opt/TAG_SUCCESS ]]'
    ExecStart=/usr/bin/rm /opt/TAG_SUCCESS
    Restart=on-failure
    RestartSec=30
```

Where the script `tag.sh` will `touch /ack/TAG_SUCCESS` at the end of execution. I believe this gets pretty close to the desired behavior because `ExecStartPre` will sequentially execute, waiting for successful completion before calling `ExecStart` and the unit is only considered `Starting` once `ExecStart` is called by which point we're sure we've completed the startup task.

But this still feels like a giant hack?

Comment: This worked well for me, except that I also had to set `RemainAfterExit=yes` to have the unit stay "active" so that other units can depend on it.

Comment: Consider `ConditionPathExists=!/opt/TAG_SUCCESS` to not need the `ExecStartPre`s.

Answer (score 0):

After looking around a little bit, I found the systemd's `notify`-type has the `oneshot` property combined with the `exec` property:

> Behavior of notify is similar to exec; however, it is expected that the service sends a notification message via sd_notify(3) or an equivalent call when it has finished starting up. systemd will proceed with starting follow-up units after this notification message has been sent. If this option is used, NotifyAccess= (see below) should be set to open access to the notification socket provided by systemd. If NotifyAccess= is missing or set to none, it will be forcibly set to main.

In which:

> The exec type is similar to simple, but the service manager will consider the unit started immediately after the main service binary has been executed. The service manager will delay starting of follow-up units until that point. (Or in other words: simple proceeds with further jobs right after fork() returns, while exec will not proceed before both fork() and execve() in the service process succeeded.) Note that this means systemctl start command lines for exec services will report failure when the service's binary cannot be invoked successfully (for example because the selected User= doesn't exist, or the service binary is missing)

I.e. to combine `simple` and `oneshot` behaviour:

```
# <your service>.service
[Unit]
Description=Your awesome service

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/your-daemon-script
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=30
NotifyAccess=all
```

```
# your-daemon-script
# Start everything
# ...
# If an error happens here, the service will restart
# If everything went fine systemd-notify --ready is used to notify systemd about that.
# After notifying systemd, systemd will switch the services state into ready and then starts other services which had to wait for this serivce to get ready.
systemd-notify --ready
```